# How to avoid confirmation message when executing a .reg file with shellexecute command

Tags: delphi, registry, message, shellexecute, confirmation

In my program I check for a registry key at startup and if somehow it does not exist I execute the reg file located in the application folder wit the help of ShellExecute command. How can I avoid getting confimation messages when executing this command. Is there a way to do that or as per security reasons it's not possible?

Comment: Don't execute the reg file. Use the registry API directly.

Comment: I'm sure the advice you gave is valuable but could you please explain as to why I shouldn't do it this way? And one more thing, the registry file I want to execute contains tons of entries which were automatically inserted by a data aware grid components. If I try to write it manually wouldn't it mean a waste of time?

Comment: For example, how will you deal with the registry redirector on 64 bit systems?

Comment: I trust this reg key is not in `HKLM`. Otherwise you won't be able to import it.

Comment: also, you will need admin rights to run Regedit in UAC environment. UAC warning dialog will popup for sure, asking the user to confirm.

Comment: @kobik that's another reason to prefer `reg import`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, `reg` looks like a designated tool for this task. but should be tested in UAC enabled OS.

Comment: Sounds like your application is setting registry keys and values that belong in an installer rather than executed from your application. This also avoids problems with UAC when calling `regedit.exe` or `reg.exe`. If you really need to do this, please use the registry API as often regedit/reg are blocked in Enterprise environments and even if they're not you have no way to check if it succeeded or do error handling (that's what API's are for).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the /s command-line switch.

Comment: And how do I do it in Delphi? Do I still use ShellExecute? An example would be appreciated

Comment: ShellExecute would work fine. Myself I would use `reg import` rather then `regedit`.

Comment: link to MS broken, as it uses to be

Comment: The link is not working anymore.

Comment: I was unable to find the new location of that document and therefore will remove the link

Answer (score 17):

It's possible.  Two methods are:

1. %windir%\system32\regedit.exe **/s** file.reg
2. %windir%\system32\reg.exe import file.reg

Either will silently import file.reg into the registry.

Comment: this worked, except it now prompts that you have to be in Admin privileges, so just as many prompts.

Comment: For the 64-bit era use regedt32.exe instead, and you do need to run as elevated admin as per comment above.

Answer (score 3):

try this for importing the *.reg file,

```
  procedure ImportRegistry;
       var
        strProgram :String ;
        strCommand :String ;
        fileOne   :String ;
      begin

fileOne:=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+  'my_Resources\Default.reg';
strProgram := 'REGEDIT' ;
strProgram := strProgram + #0 ;
strCommand := '/SC /C ' + ExtractShortPathName(fileOne) ;
strCommand := strCommand + #0 ;

if ShellExecute(0,nil,@strProgram[1],@strCommand[1],nil,SW_HIDE) <= 32 then
  begin
        ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ; //if there is any error in importing
  end;


end;
```

Also you can try this link [unitEXRegistry.pas](http://read.pudn.com/downloads10/sourcecode/delphi_control/38972/unitEXRegistry.pas__.htm)

This unitEXRegistry.pas unit has very useful functions to export registry file and also import silently the exported *.reg file

```
       procedure exportREgis;
        var
         texpr : TExRegistry;
        begin
         texpr:=TExRegistry.Create;
         texpr.RootKey:=HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
         texpr.OpenKeyReadOnly('\MyKey');
         texpr.ExportKey (ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'ExportedReg.reg');
         texpr.Free; 
       end;
```

Then to import you can use(silently)

```
     procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        var
         texpr : TExRegistry;
        begin
          texpr:=TExRegistry.Create;
          texpr.ImportRegFile('c:\myReg.reg');
          texpr.Free;
       end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a bug in REG IMPORT - it writes the success message to STDERR instead of STDOUT.

The following .bat code solves the problem.  The success message is discarded, but the failure message is displayed.

```
SET RegError=%TEMP%\RegError.txt
REG IMPORT "%Settings.reg%" 2>"%RegError%" && DEL /Q "%RegError%" || @(ECHO Error importing %Settings.reg%: & TYPE "%RegError%" & PAUSE)
SET RegError=
```